# Lost focus after using MessageDialog in TableViewer in JFace

Tags: eclipse, plugins, jface, tableviewer, messagedialog

I have a strange problem with `MessageDialog`. I have a dialog which holds a `TableViewer`. My plan is that when a user select something in the `TableViewer`, it will pop up a warning dialog. the code is like below:

```
contextTableViewer = new TableViewer(tableContainer, SWT.BORDER | SWT.FULL_SELECTION);
contextTableViewer.addSelectionChangedListener(new ISelectionChangedListener() {
  public void selectionChanged(SelectionChangedEvent event) {
    ...
    if () {
       Shell pshell = Display.getCurrent().getActiveShell();
        MessageDialog.openWarning(pshell, "something", "something");
    }
    ...
  }
```

my problem is that, after the warning dialog pop up, I loss the focus. For instance, I need to click "Cancel" button twice to close the dialog that holds the `TableViewer`. I tried to use `setFocus()` to set the focus back, but it didn't work. Any tips? Thanks very much.

Comment: It probably makes no different here but you can just call `getShell()` in a dialog, no need for `Display.getCurrent().getActiveShell()`

Comment: Do you mean you loose focus while the MessageDialog is displayed or after it is closed?

Comment: Thanks, I just tried ur method, `getShell()` didn't work as well. I also tried `getShell().setActive()`, `getShell.setFocus()`, after the openWarning, they didn't work~

Comment: After. After I close the MessageDialog, I need to click the "Cancel" button twice to close the dialog that holds the table.

Comment: I can't reproduce this. Check the .log file in the workspace .metadata directory for any related messages.

Comment: I just recall that it happened before, also in the TableViewer, one of the column in the table allow users to edit the values unless it is 0 (for example). If it is 0, it will pop up a MessageDialog. After I close the MessageDialog, I need to click the cell, which I was editing, twice to get the focus back.

Comment: BTW, when I debug my program, I set a breakpoint in the method `cancelPressed()`. The first time I click the "Cancel" button, the debugger dosen't jump to the breakpoint, until I click the button for the second time.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why it happens, I solve the problem by mocking a mouse clicking on the dialog to get the focus back.